# Validity of HashMap definition in Java?

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

```
class Node {
    long data;
    Node node;
    int rank;
}
```

1. `private Map<Long, Node> map = new HashMap<>();`
2. `private Map<Long, Node> map = new HashMap<Long,Node>();`

I am implementing hashmap of class Node

My question is the validity of the 2 above mentioned Hashmaps.(whether both are coreect or not?).
If they are valid what is the difference in the two initializations?

Comment: From Java7 Number 1 is supported. The compiler infers the types. But before Java7 only Number 2 was supported.

Answer (score 3):

According the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

> In Java SE 7 and later, you can replace the type arguments required to
>   invoke the constructor of a generic class with an empty set of type
>   arguments (<>) as long as the compiler can determine, or infer, the
>   type arguments from the context. This pair of angle brackets, <>, is
>   informally called the diamond.

From Java 7, both are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid ways of creating Maps but following is the latest where we don't need to declare the datatype on the right. 
private Map map = new HashMap<>();

Basically Java is moving towards being a less verbose language.